# flutter: how to call class inside stack?

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to set background image for Imagecarousel class in flutter and i'm using stack so the background image will set only for the carousel and this is what i want because i dont want the background image to show on other blocks when scroll page, but the problem is i can't call the class child:ImageCarousel?() here it shows me error, any help?

```
child: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                             Stack(children: <Widget>[
                                Image(
                             colorBlendMode: BlendMode.modulate,
                             image: new AssetImage('assets/images/home-back.png'),
                             )],
                    ),         
                child: ImageCarousel(),
              ),
```

Comment: you want to set a background for your stack or you want to call a class on it?

Comment: i used  stack cuz i want to set background image only for the carousel

Comment: Please do not use snippets for code that cannot be run by the snippets.

Comment: i know that but my code it too long so its impossible to add, however i wanted to call class inside stack only

Answer (score 1):

you should put image in box decoration

```
Container(
      height: 120.0,
      
      width: 120.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(
              'assets/images/home-back.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
    child:Imagecarousel(),
    )
```

Comment: thank you but this works on full page background and i want only carousel background

Comment: you can change the height and width , did you do that ?

Comment: yes the problem is child:ImageCarousel() can't be called here it gives error

Comment: The method 'Imagecarousel' isn't defined for the type 'MyHomePage'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Imagecarousel'.

Comment: i had spelling mistake ,  i wrote Imagecarousel instead of ImageCarousel , replace the name  and tell me the result

Comment: i did change that but it's not working too, actually it will work in a way if i make the background scrollable , is there a way to make background image scrollable?

Comment: oh sorry , i don't know how to, you can ask it as a separate question